# Why not a sync version of async APIs like in XHR?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

Idea in my mind was all `WebAPI`s are `async` because of things are being processed outside of `JavaScript` runtime. But I got to know that I can send `XMLHttpRequest` requests synchronously. So I got few questions around this.

Are `XMLHttpRequest` APIs part of `Javascript` runtime?
If so, How is it possible to send requests asynchronously?
Why not implement other useful APIs to Javascript it self without exposing them as `WebAPI`s?

Are `XMLHttpRequest` APIs part of `WebAPI`s?
Then, why there are no other synchronous APIs? Why not `setTimeout` synchronous API?

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is part of the *browser*, not JavaScript. The ability to make synchronous calls is accompanied by the penalty of freezing up user interface until the request completes. It was basically a design error that couldn't be fixed until recently.

Comment: "*because of things are being processed outside of JavaScript runtime.*" - no, that's not the reason why things are asynchronous. There are many synchronous web apis as well, e.g. the whole DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are XMLHttpRequest APIs part of Javascript runtime?

That depends on what you mean by "JavaScript runtime." They aren't part of JavaScript's standard library, no. They're a host-provided feature in web browsers.

> Are XMLHttpRequest APIs part of WebAPIs?

Yes, it's a web API.

> Then, why there are no other synchronous APIs?

There are. Nearly all DOM operations are synchronous, for instance. But things that will take any significant amount of time (like network requests) and are initiated from the main UI thread (which is where JavaScript runs in browsers by default) are best done asynchronously, to avoid blocking that thread and preventing UI updates. So `XMLHttpRequest` is async by default (and using the flag to make it synchronous is getting deprecated), `fetch` is always async, and various other operations that may take time are asynchronous.

In a modern environment,¹ using async APIs is just as easy as using synchronous APIs, thanks to `async` functions:

```
async function showMoreData() {
    const response = await fetch("/more/data/please");
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    for (const entry of data) {
         // ...do something...
    }
}
```

---

¹ "modern environments" - most browsers support `async` functions natively now, and if you have to target IE11 or other obsolete browsers (which sadly many of us do!), you can use tools like Babel to convert your modern code into older code that will run in those environments. You write up-to-date stuff, they turn it into something IE11 can understand.

Comment: For some reason I assumed things like DOM operations APIs are part of Javascript (I guess it's JavaScript's standard library APIs in correct terms) and I thought that's why they are synchronous. Apparently not.

Comment: @s1n7ax - That's perfectly understandable, the first (and often only) place people learn about JavaScript tends to be in the browser, so things get a bit lumped together. :-) JavaScript's standard library is pretty small (even `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are host-provided). JavaScript is a general-purpose language that isn't restricted to or specific to browsers, so the DOM isn't part of it. If you ever want to know if something is host-provided or built-in, you can tell by checking [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/) -- if it's not there, it's host-provided. :-D